# Is there a script that turns a Pharo core image into something more useful, that would include an OmniBrowser?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I cannot use the most recent dev Pharo release because of some strange issues with the compiler built into Pharo. Well. I was wondering if there is a quick way to install all the nifty extras into Pharo that the core image misses, as compared to the dev image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With all non-core Pharo images come a script which was used to build that image. Just edit that file and drag&drop it on a new core.

You could also tell me what you don't like in the Pharo images so that I can enhance them.

Answer (score 4):

There is also the script I published on the Pharo wiki that I use to build my images:

http://code.google.com/p/pharo/wiki/ImageBuildScripts

Of course it is very specific to my preferences and needs, but you can take it as an example and adapt it to your own needs.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, OB itself can be easily downloaded using `ScriptLoader loadSuperOB`.

Damien adds (from comment below):

> The problem with that approach is that nobody really maintains it.
>   Moreover, you miss some configuration steps to enhance the use of OB
>   (for example, you won't have the OB-based browsers if you ask for the
>   senders of a message from a workspace)

Comment: The problem with that approach is that nobody really maintains it. Moreover, you miss some configuration steps to enhance the use of OB (for example, you won't have the OB-based browsers if you ask for the senders of a message from a workspace).

Answer (score 1):

[CommandShell](http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/1914) works with Pharo 9.10.10.  You will hit several errors as you try to load the package due to Pharo lacking MVC, but you can simply proceed past the first bunch and abandon the last one (that tries to actually open a CommandShell in Morphic).  At that point, you'll have a class called `PipeableOSProcess` that can be used very easily to grab output.  For example:

```
(PipeableOSProcess command: 'ls /bin') output
```

will return the contents of your bin directory as a string.